# What can this polynomial regression tell me about the distribution of my error values?

Tags: regression, distributions, regression-coefficients, polynomial

I'm working with a list of errors in some process that can be expressed as small percentages. Since they're errors we hope they're small overall and expect them to be approximately normally distributed. It's common practice in my field to sort this list and plot them like this (dummy data):

[image: Actual values of the errors sorted low to high]

We can make some qualitative interpretation based on the shape of the visual curve made by the tops of the bars but these are hard to quantify or proceduralize when you have a lot of sets of errors like this and want to identify "interesting" ones.

So it occurred to me to fit a polynomial and see what happens. Using [scipy's ODR package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) I get this cubic approximation:

[image: Cubic approximation of the errors]

The function is (rounded to 4dp) $f(x) = 0.0016x^3 - 0.0075x^2 + 0.1157x + 0.4269$.

My question is: **Can the coefficients of this function tell us anything about the distributional features of the data**? I feel that *surely* the answer is "yes" but I can't make a straightforward connection between the coefficients and features I know how to calculate such as variance, skew etc.

My motivation is mainly curiosity but I'm also interested to see if there's a novel visualization or summary technique we could use here. We do of course already calculate moments by traditional means.

Comment: What are the axes on your plots?

Comment: @Dave Good question. The y-axis is the error, the x-axis is ordinal position of the value in the list of values sorted from low to high. In fact I forgot that I transformed the x-axis values to centre them on 0, which may or may not confuse things -- I expect the line to pass through (0, 0), or close to it.

Comment: This visualization is tantamount to plotting the empirical CDF in a strange and visually confusing fashion (and with axes flipped).  The coefficients of your fit can't tell you *anything* without making strong assumptions about the form the ECDF might take.  Assuming it inverts a cubic, as done here, would be an unusual and not very tractable model.  It would be better, IMHO, to learn standard techniques for assessing distributions, including qq plots and plots of ECDFs; and to apply standard procedures of distribution fitting, even though the lack of novelty might be disappointing.

Comment: @whuber You're right of course -- I'm very much aware of and already using those methods. I was curious about whether there's anything worth further investigation here, especially as analysts are currently looking at and interpreting the shape of this curve (in the form of the bar chart) very non-rigorously. The ECDF connection IS an interesting perspective. I'd be interested to see that fleshed out as an answer if you think that would be worthwhile. It may help to inform what our analysts are doing, if nothing else!

Comment: There's really not much to say.  If I understand correctly, the plot uses bars to represent $(r,x)$ pairs where $r$ is a centered rank and $x$ is the corresponding value.  The ECDF plots $(x,p)$ pairs for *percentage points* $p=(r-r_\text{min})/(r_{\text{max}}-r_{\text{min}}),$ which means your cubic is equivalent to $x=f(p)$ where $f$ is still a cubic polynomial.  Thus, this method models the ECDF as the local inverse of some cubic $p=f^{-1}(x),$ but it uses an inappropriate fitting method because the values of $x$ are by construction strongly serially correlated.